# How to redirect while ignoring some of the text

Tags: command-line, io-redirection

Some potential duplicates may be the following:

[How to ignore specific lines from being redirected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594844/how-to-ignore-specific-lines-from-being-redirected)

BUT I can't extrapolate from that to solve my problem. So, I am asking here instead.

So, here is what I got so far:

```
sbcl --noinform --non-interactive --eval "(ql:quickload :lambda-calculus-compiler)" < test.lisp > x.txt
```

I am trying to evaluate a lisp file, read a text file `test.lisp` and use it as the input code to `(ql:quickload :lambda-calculus-compiler`. When loading this a function gets called the reads which will read the contents in `test.lisp` and then this evaluation will be redirected to `x.txt`.

Here are the contents of `x.txt` after this operation:

```
To load "lambda-calculus-compiler":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    lambda-calculus-compiler
; Loading "lambda-calculus-compiler"
(((LAMBDA (N) (LAMBDA (M) (LAMBDA (F) (LAMBDA (Z) ((M F) ((N F) Z))))))
  (LAMBDA (F) (LAMBDA (Z) (F (F (F Z))))))
 (LAMBDA (F) (LAMBDA (Z) (F (F (F Z))))))
```

I want to ignore or get rid of

```
To load "lambda-calculus-compiler":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    lambda-calculus-compiler
; Loading "lambda-calculus-compiler"
```

which is the output of `(ql:quickload :lambda-calculus-compiler)`.

Any help will be appreciated. Please don't mark this a duplicate. As I mentioned I can't extrapolate from answers like the one I linked above.

Thanks.

Comment: You could pipe through `sed '1,/Loading "lambda-calculus-compiler"/ d'`, which removes the lines starting with 1 through the one containing that phrase. However, that may not be your best option. I'm not familiar with sbcl, but you should read its [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sbcl) and see if it has options to suppress that output to start with. `--noprint` or `--noinform` maybe?

Comment: @frabjous can you write an answer please? im not familiar with piping

Comment: Pipes are a really basic concept. It's not a shame not to know something - not researching it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to pipe the command through sed before redirecting to the file:

```
sbcl --noinform --non-interactive --eval "(ql:quickload :lambda-calculus-compiler)" < test.lisp |
  sed '1,/Loading "lambda-calculus-compiler"/ d' > x.txt
```

This removes the lines starting with 1 through the one after that containing that phrase.

But I suspect there may be other options specific to sbcl as I mentioned in the comments.